# R changing names when there is ä ü ö

Tags: r, formatting, settings

OK, this is an extremly annoying problem and I was not able to find a solution on the internet, therefore I come to you.

When importing data sets that contain German names with Umlaut (ä, ö, ü), R modifies the names. Somethin like `Möhlin` -> `M<f6>hlin`.

When writing code word containing Umlaut cause no problem, until saving the script. After reloading a save script all my beloved Umlaut are modified. Aka all the names of my plots, the name of the variables, etc etc ...

Please, anyone can help me ?

Comment: http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~izahn/posts/reading-data-with-non-native-encoding-in-r/

Comment: In which encoding does your editor save the code? You might need to change this. Try ANSI.

Comment: @KarstenW. You mean ASCII? Also, isn't ASCII the real problem here?

Comment: How can I determine in which encoding does my editor save the code? (sorry, i am beginner)

Comment: When you _save the script_, are you doing that within R or in an external text editor?

Comment: I save the scripts within R. Another follow up beginner question : Why I save my scripts in an external text editor?

Comment: What does it tell you when you type `Sys.getlocale()` into the R console?

Comment: "LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252"

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with the internal editor on my installation. Which R version are you using? Also, what would be example code that shows this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the locale:

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "German")
```

Comment: Are you on Mac or Windows?

Comment: i am on windows

Answer (score 0):

Try changing default codepage to UTF-8 in RStudio via:

```
Tools - Global Options - Code - Saving - Default Text Encoding - UTF-8
```

then restart RStudio and save and reopen your script with umlauts.

Comment: Still not working :/.  I have restarted the session also.

Comment: @Danka Note that he is referring to RStudio, not the standard R app.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just try to make sure all your files are UTF-8 encoded, ie. know their Umlauts.

Thus, when [writing](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html) and [reading](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) files, try to always explicitly set the file encoding to "UTF-8". 
For instance, when writing `df` to file,

```
write.csv(tt, "output.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

The same logic applies to `read.csv()`, etc. 
Note that opening files that way will only work properly when you saved them as UTF-8 in the first place.

I know that some people like to use [stringr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html) for string manipulation in general when working with non-English text, but I have never used it.